# Chrome extension to automatically send button click on specific page once specific time-of-day is reached

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble locating am example Chrome Extension background script that I can use to model for this task.

- Extension's functionality limited to a specific web page.
- After some time, possibly minutes 'after' the web page has been loaded, fire a button click event when the following conditions are true:

  - A specific button on this page is enabled
  - A certain time of day is reached

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "Certain time of day" requirement, have you looked into the Alarm API?

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#method-create

The create function has a couple of different, optional parameters, one of which is `when`:

Time at which the alarm should fire, in milliseconds past the epoch (e.g. Date.now() + n).

Google also has several examples of extension that run on specific sites listed here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples